# Printing a large dataframe across pages

Tags: pandas, printing

I have a need to print a large table across multiple pages which contains both header rows and a “header”column. Representative of what I would like to achieve is:

https://github.com/EricG-Personal/table_print/blob/master/table.png

I do not want the contents of any cell to be clipped, split between pages, or auto-scaled to be smaller. Each page should have the appropriate header rows and each page should have the appropriate header column (the ID column).

The only aspect not depicted is that some of the cells would contain image data.

Can I achieve this with pandas?

What possible solutions do I have when attempting to print a large dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas has no such capabilities, it wasn't designed for that in the first place. 
I'd suggest converting your DataFrame to excel sheet and print that using MS Excel. It has -to the best of my knowledge- all what you need.

Comment: exporting to an excel sheet is not an option for me.

Comment: it needs to be printed direct from an application. requiring a user to go through an extra step of export and then print is not a good user experience.